# Adding fragment with animation causes fragment to flash before animation begins

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment and animating it down from the top of the screen. The animation works perfectly, but the whole fragment very quickly appears, then disappears, and then the animation begins. How can I get rid of this flash?

Fragment: ( MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout to calculate the yFraction )

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"/>
```

showMenu called from onClick() that triggers the animation:
private void showMenu() {

```
    mDidSlideOut = true;

    // Get the fragment manager.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Set the animations.
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_fragment_in, R.animator.slide_fragment_out);

    // Add to back stack
    ft.addToBackStack(m_backStackName);

    // Add the fragment.
    DropDownFragment newFragment = new DropDownFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.drop_down_container, newFragment);

    // Start the animated transition.
    ft.commit();
}
```

Slide in animation:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:valueFrom="-1.0"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:propertyName="yFraction"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:duration="5000">
</objectAnimator>
```

The flash is very fast, and like I said, the animation works quite well.

Comment: Hi Siriss, did you solve your problem? I am facing same issue on my device. Meanwhile on some others it can't be reproduced.

Comment: Not really. I will post my "solution" today, but I was not really happy with it.

Comment: "The problem is that custom fragment animation starts before our layout is measured" http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/